# Spring-WS : specifying the Content-Type

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers, spring-ws

I have a Spring Webservice based on `AbstractJDomPayloadEndpoint`. This service works fine, except that my client needs the HTTP header `Content-Type` to be set to the right charset (utf-8 in my case). I cant find where I can configure that.

I tried writing a simple servlet `Filter` :

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

But this doesnt change the headers at all. I suspect that the content type header is set by Spring-WS, and the response is commited, so nothing I set in a filter will have an impact.

My appserver is WebLogic 9.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your filter code will fail because by the time `doFilter()` completes, the response will have been fully committed, and you won't be allowed to change the content type header.

I suggest writing a subclass of `HttpServletResponseWrapper`, overriding the `setContentType()` and/or `setCharacterEncoding()` methods to set the value to the one you want. You then pass the instance of the wrapper (which wraps the original response) to the `doFilter()`.

Comment: Thanks ! Why didnt I think of a HttpServletResponseWrapper ? Still, it would be nice to have a way to configure Spring-WS to use the right encoding directly ...