# How to access HTTP headers in Spring-ws endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, http-headers, spring-ws

How can I access HTTP headers in Spring-ws endpoint?

My code looks like this:

```
public class MyEndpoint extends AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint {
  protected Object invokeInternal(Object arg) throws Exception {
      MyReq request = (MyReq) arg;
      // need to access some HTTP headers here
      return createMyResp();
  }
}
```

`invokeInternal()` gets only the unmarshalled JAXB object as the parameter. How can I access HTTP headers that came with the request inside `invokeInternal()`?

One way that would probably work is to create a  Servlet filter that stores header values to `ThreadLocal` variable that is then accessed inside `invokeInternal()`, but is there a nicer, more spring-like way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add these methods. The [`TransportContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/transport/context/TransportContextHolder.html) will hold some data related to transport (HTTP in this case) in a thread local variable. You can access `HttpServletRequest` from the [`TransportContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/transport/context/TransportContext.html).

```
protected HttpServletRequest getHttpServletRequest() {
    TransportContext ctx = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
    return ( null != ctx ) ? ((HttpServletConnection ) ctx.getConnection()).getHttpServletRequest() : null;
}

protected String getHttpHeaderValue( final String headerName ) {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = getHttpServletRequest();
    return ( null != httpServletRequest ) ? httpServletRequest.getHeader( headerName ) : null;
}
```

Comment: This works great, and you can use `TransportContextHolder#setTransportContext` in unit tests if you need to mock the header values on the `HttpServletConnection`. For that you can use `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest`. Keep in mind that this whole construct uses a `ThreadLocal`, so you can't access these values in execution pools that use their own threads! Retrieve the needed values before passing any work to a pool.

Answer (score 4):

You can access to HTTP headers in Spring SOAP Endpoint by injecting ***HttpServletRequest***.

For example, you need to get *Autorization* header (you use Basic authentication).

*SOAP request:*

```
POST http://localhost:8025/ws HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Content-Length: 287
Host: localhost:8025
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tok="http://abcdef.com/integration/adapter/services/Token">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tok:GetTokenRequest>
      </tok:GetTokenRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

*@Endpoint* java class

```
@Endpoint
@Slf4j
public class TokenEndpoint {

    public static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://abcdef.com/integration/adapter/services/Token";
    private static final String AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";

    private final HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
    private final TokenService tokenService;

    public TokenEndpoint(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, TokenService tokenService) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetTokenRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetTokenResponse getToken(@RequestPayload GetTokenRequest request) {
        String auth = servletRequest.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);
        log.debug("Authorization header is {}", auth);
        return tokenService.getToken(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but is harder to unit test with a `MockWebServiceClient`, as you can't inject/access the `HttpServletRequest` there. So the other (accepted) solution is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem (see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914807/spring-ws-specifying-the-content-type/3927270)). I needed to add a Content-Type header to my WS. I went the road of the Servlet Filter. Most of the time, you should not need to change HTTP headers in a webservice. But ... there is sometime a diference between theory and practice.