# Change Spring WS Fault status code from 500 to 400

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I have built Spring WS application (based on Spring WS 2.2.3) that exposes a small web service with couple of Operations. Each Operation receives input parameters to search a backend database and return response. Some of the parameters are mandatory (e.g. Street Name) and the Client have requested that if a request to the service is missing some of these mandatory parameters (e.g. empty Street Name) then my service should return proper SOAP Fault with HTTP status of 400.

My exception handling is working fine and I am able to return the correct SOAP Fault to the client if some a required parameter was missing form the request message and Spring WS takes care of the rest by wrapping a SOAP Fault and sends it back to the client with status code of 500 like the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 503
Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 22:28:02 GMT

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">Street Name is required</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Which is good except that I really want the HTTP status code to be **'400 Bad Request'** instead of the '**500 Internal Server Error**' I can't figure out how to change the status code from 500 to 400 and get similar response like the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 503
Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 22:28:02 GMT

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">Street Name is required</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914807/spring-ws-specifying-the-content-type/3927270

Comment: Sorry but the link above is regarding specifying the content type. I would like to specify the response code e.g. 400, 401, 500 based on the error type my Web Server develop.

Comment: According to the https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/:

In case of a SOAP error while processing the request, the SOAP HTTP server MUST issue an HTTP 500 "Internal Server Error" response and include a SOAP message in the response containing a SOAP Fault element (see section 4.4) indicating the SOAP processing error.